# Path Planning using moveIt with a closed-loop chain

Tags: ros, moveit, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am working on an robot arm which happens to be a closed-loop kinematic chain.
I achieved to have a somewhat accurate simulation with gazebo7.

Now I have installed ros Indigo and I want to do some path planning with moveIt, and view it with rViz.
So, I set up my robot to get the .sdrf file and everything works... except when I close my loop with the last joint..
The simulation doesnt take into account this joint.

When I check the shell it tells me that:

```
[ERROR] [1469600994.580670671]: Joint 'lely_arm__verin2/base' not found in model 'origins'
```

also:

```
[ERROR] [1469601613.254367292]: Kinematics solver N21srv_kinematics_plugin19SrvKinematicsPluginE does not support joint group g.  Error: This plugin only supports joint groups which are chains
```

Is it plain impossible to work on a closed loop or did i miss something?

Thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240463/path-planning-using-moveit-with-a-closed-loop-chain/) by [Soho_](https://answers.ros.org/users/27617/soho_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

moveIt and rViz rely on URDF which does not support closed kinematic chains. See this discussion:
http://answers.ros.org/question/9050/using-ros-for-a-delta-robot/?answer=13094#post-id-13094

People seem to work around this by opening the loop and then closing it using their own constraints.

---

Originally posted by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) with karma: 283 on 2016-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Soho_](https://answers.ros.org/users/27617/soho_/) on 2016-08-15**:
I don't understand how sould I add these constraints
It seems you can bypass the problem with clever solution for parellel robots, however it is not one here..